# Comments somehow overflow when adding a new one

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

[image]

This happens under Chrome 6 every time I try to add a comment on that page.

If I reload the page, everything is back to normal

Comment: another post, chrome6 as well: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/607/how-can-i-backup-my-blogspot-com-hosted-blog

Comment: Chrome 6 on Mac also.

Answer (score 2):

That's odd, I can reproduce in Chrome 5 as well. (Please note that we explicitly do not support beta browsers.)

Ah, I see -- this is a CSS issue with not specifying width of the comment box properly.

Comment: Good to know about the browsers, though that's going to be hard on this site I reckon ;-)

Comment: in my w3m it looks strange as well, does this count as a betabrowser too? :)