# Add comment button overflows into sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Comments somehow overflow when adding a new one](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57/comments-somehow-overflow-when-adding-a-new-one)

On Safari 5, MacOS 10.5.8, when adding a comment the `Add Comment` button overflows into the sidebar.  I have the browser displayed full-screen on a 15" MacBook Pro.  I apologize for the lack of hand-drawn circles.

[image: Display of issue]

**EDIT**:  Update -- the linked picture doesn't show it, but long comments also appear to bleed into the sidebar.  The entire container appears to be too wide at least in my browser.

Comment: Noticed this also Google Chrome Mac 5.0.375.86

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 3.0.10 as well has this issue

Comment: As does Firefox 3.5.9 on Linux